# Streaming file to Android Client

Tags: php, android, download

I want to download a file with android and so i stream the file with php with the following function

```
function stream($fileName,$fileSize,$fName){
        //header("Pragma:public");
        //header("Expires:0");
        //header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        //header("Cache-Control:private",false);
        header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"".$fName."\";");
        header("Content-Type:application/octet-stream");  
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary");
        header("Content-Length:".$fileSize);
        readfile($fileName);
}
```

But the download does not work on an android device. On my computer, it isn't a problem. I already found a solution on http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/ but this didn't helped me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [my blog posting that you cite](http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/), the success of your download on Android devices depends on multiple factors, which cannot be told by reading your code:

- Your $fileName must contain an uppercase extension.
- The pure URL that you call to download must contain all information needed for the download to start. No POST parameters may be involved, they will not be forwarded to the Android Download Manager and thus the download will fail. GET parameters (query string) are ok.
- Also you did not obey the blog posting in all details:
  **There is a semicolon after your Content-Disposition header which is fatal.**

I also recommend to start with the Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers ONLY. When you got it working on Android, you can still add any other headers that you want to send. But do not forget to re-test on Android (multiple versions if possible) when you are complete. Android is really picky about some of those headers (or should I say "bitchy"?).

If all of this does not help you will have to provide some more information about your case. What exactly happens when you try it?  What URL do you call. What are the parameters passed to your function?